# Cutting a hole in baubles

Tags: cutting, acrylic-glass

When working with acrylic clear baubles like these
[image: clear bauble]

What method can be used to cut a clean hole in the side to create a diarama within the bauble?

I imagine using a dremel would create a jagged edge which would be hard to smooth out without creating a scratched look on the edge.  I would like a clean edge if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you require a circular opening and have access to a laser cutter AND the plastic is acrylic and not polycarbonate, the baubles can be cut with the laser cutter. The edges would be polished by the laser to a smooth edge.

Makerspaces are the best option for finding a laser cutter. It has to be a CO2 laser rather than the lower cost, lower power diode lasers as the latter operate at the wrong frequency.

I would be able to accomplish your objective, but I find no method of contact in the SE system.